# Cannot start the MySql service on XAMPP, Windows 10

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have an issue when I start the MySQL service on XAMPP, setted on the 3306 port.
Apache works, but after a few seconds I have started MySQL, XAMPP returns me:

```
19:01:57  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
19:01:57  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
19:01:57  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
19:01:57  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
19:01:57  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
19:01:57  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

and in the *mysql_error.log*:

```
2019-12-02 19:01:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-12-02 19:01:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-12-02 19:01:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-12-02 19:01:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-12-02 19:01:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-12-02 19:01:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*50331648 to 2*5242880 bytes; LSN=795678
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5242880 bytes
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5242880 bytes
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=795678
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 795678; transaction id 1046
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-12-02 19:01:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

IDK what to do, I've also tryed disabling the Avira Firewal, deleting the ibdata1, checking the port scanner(Netstat) and changing the port on 3307, but it gives me the same error..
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Anything else in the mysql_error.log? Looks like you are missing lines.

Comment: @JesusUzcanga of course, I uploaded the file here... [mysql_error.log](https://gofile.io/?c=KUz1nM)

Comment: And the MY.INI CONFIG FILE HERE: [my.ini](https://gofile.io/?c=2RhRw7)